# How to start threads in a graph?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am supposed to write kind of company simulation, there are `Manufactures` and `Shops`. Each one is separately working group of threads and they are in some distance from others(like in kilometers). I thought that the solution for that problem might be creating a graph, so that each node would be manufacture or shop. That might solve the distance problem. However, I don't know how to implement this. My first thought was implementing `JGraphT` library, because that way I can use edge's weight as length. But event though, I don't know how to make starting group of threads depending on the node that is currently created. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you going to be applying moderately-to-very complex graph operations to this structure, e.g. finding minimum spanning trees or hamiltonian cycles and all that; or do you just want a graph-like representation?  If the latter then `JGraphT` is probably overkill - you can just implement an abstract `Node` class with a `distance` property and a `List` of connected nodes, as well as `Manufacturer` and `Shop` node subclasses

Comment: All `Manufactures` and `Shops` are going to be started with `Executor` and there will be one thread visiting `Manufacture` taking `object` from it and giving it to `Shop`. So I don't need to do moderately-to-very complex graph operations. I will be needing edges weight. However, I was thinking to put shops and manufactures onto two `BlockingQueues`. I thought it might take a few steps. 1.create node, whenever node is created define if Manufacture/Shop. 2.If node start group of `Threads`, kind of special pattern. 3. If node created and threads started, go to 1. I'm not sure if I see it right?

Answer (score 0):

JGraphT is probably overkill for your needs but should work, here's a code snippet that defines a class that represents the shop or manufacturer (you could extend this class into two distinct `Shop` and `Manufacturer` classes if you need to further specialize their behavior). The class holds the thread group and handles adding threads and stopping them (which you should do when removing the object from the graph, for instance).

```
public class Site {
  private String name;
  private ThreadGroup tGroup;
  public Site(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    tGroup = new ThreadGroup(name);
  }
  public void addThread(Runnable r) {
    new Thread(tGroup, r);
  }
  public void stopThreads() {
    tGroup.interrupt();
  }
}

Graph<Site, DefaultEdge> graph = new WeightedGraph<Site, DefaultEdge>();
Site shop1 = new Site("Shop1");
Site man1  = new Site("Manufacturer1");

graph.addVertex(shop1);
graph.addVertex(man1);
graph.addEdge(shop1, man1).setEdgeWeight(5.0);
shop1.addThread(new Runnable() { //thread code here });
// ...
```

Comment: The `Manufacture/ShopPattern` are about to be a group of threads also. In class that starts graph I have `ExecutorService` that starts both patterns as many times as I wish (each one has its id). So either I don't see Your solution working for me, or I don't understand it properly (if so, could You describe it to me?).